# Existence of a differentiable function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ satisfying $f(0)=1$ and $f(x+1)=\exp\left(3x^2+1\right)f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-equations

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable function that satisfies
$$ f(0)=1 \\ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \quad f(x+1)=\exp\left(3x^2+1\right)f(x)$$

I think a function $f$ exist which satisfies these conditions, but I don't have any evidence justify my opinion.

Can anyone prove or disprove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As pointed out by Kavi Rama Murthy and other contributors, I have rewritten my answer.**

---

Note that $f(0)=1$ implies $f(x)>0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Taking logarithm gives $\ln\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}=3x^2+1$.

For any $x\in\mathbb{Z}^+$,

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{x-1}\ln\frac{f(k+1)}{f(k)} & =\sum_{k=0}^{x-1}(3k^2+1) \\
\ln\frac{f(x)}{f(0)} & =3\cdot\frac{x(x-1)(2x-1)}{6}+x \\
\ln f(x) & =\frac{2x^3-3x^2+3x}{2} \\
\end{align*}
$$

For any $x\in\mathbb{Z}^-$,

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=x}^{-1}\ln\frac{f(k+1)}{f(k)} & =\sum_{k=x}^{-1}(3k^2+1) \\
\ln\frac{f(0)}{f(x)} & =3\cdot\frac{(-x)(-x+1)(-2x+1)}{6}+(-x) \\
\ln f(x) & =\frac{2x^3-3x^2+3x}{2} \\
\end{align*}
$$

Therefore, $\ln f(x)=\frac{2x^3-3x^2+3x}{2}$ for any $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.

To fill up the gap between consecutive integral values of $x$ with the differentiability requirement fulfilled, it can be assumed that $\ln f(x)=\frac{2x^3-3x^2+3x}{2}+\pi(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ where $\pi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function with the following conditions.

1. $\pi(x)=0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.
2. $\pi(x+1)=\pi(x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $\pi$ is periodic.

Therefore, $f(x)=\exp{\left(\frac{2x^3-3x^2+3x}{2}+\pi(x)\right)}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is one example. There are plenty of other functions satisfying the given conditions.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Can you please elaborate by giving an example?

Comment: Does $f(0)=1$ justify taking natural logarithm both side?

Comment: Could you expound on how you initially inferred $\ln f(x)$ is a cubic polynomial?

Comment: 'the solution' is surely wrong. How did you get uniqueness?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy I guess so but I still cannot figure any other solution. Can you provide one?

Comment: @Yuta The hypothesis only says $\frac {f(1+x)} {f(x)}$ has  a particular form. That makes it obvious that you can start with an **arbitrary** function on $[0,1]$ subject some boundary conditions and extend it to the whole line. Are you familiar with periodic functions and periodic extension of functions form $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$ with period $1$? The situation here is similar.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy I am not so familiar with periodic extension of functions. But does it mean the solution must be periodic? $f(x)=e^{x^3-\frac{3}{2}x^2+\frac{3}{2}x}$ is not periodic.

Comment: I am not saying that the function is periodic. I am just drawing a parallel between the two situations to help you understand why there is no uniqueness.

Comment: Okay I have just edited my answer. See if I can make further improvement after I spend some more time on it.

Comment: There are many more solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g$ be any differentiable function on $[0,1]$ with $g(0)=1,  g(1)=e$ and $eg'(0)=g'(1)$. Extend $g$ to the whole line using the given equation. For example, $f=g$ on $[0,1]$, $f(x)=g(x-1)e^{3(x-1)^{2}+1}$ for $x \in [1,2]$ etc.

Comment: A typo, the equation gives $f(1)=\exp(1) f(0)$

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you. You are right.  I have corrected the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the logarithm, $f$ satisfies the linear recurrence

$$\log f(x+1)=\log f(x)+3x^2+1.$$

The solution of the homogeneous equation is just

$$\log f(x)=c.$$

A particular solution can be obtained by indeterminate coefficients, noting that the leading term must be $x^3$, and the constant term doesn't matter (it is absorbed in the homogeneous solution).

Hence,

$$(x+1)^3+a(x+1)^2+b(x+1)-x^3-ax^2-bx=3x^2+(2a+3)x+a+b+1=3x^2+1$$

gives

$$-a=b=\frac32.$$

Finally, using $\log f(0)=0$,
$$f(x)=e^{x^3-3x^2/2+3x/2}.$$

---

But the story doesn't end here. As the recurrence only relates values that are one unit apart, the constant $c$ can vary as a function of the fractional part of $x$, and the general solution is of the form

$$f(x)=e^{x^3-3x^2/2+3x/2}e^{c(\{x\})}.$$

For differentiability of $f$, $c$ must be differentiable in $[0,1)$, $c(0^+)=c(1^-)=0$ must hold, as well as $c'(0^+)=c'(1^-)$.

An example solution is

$$e^{x^3-3x^2/2+3x/2+\sin(2\pi x)}.$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a functional difference equation with solution

$$
f(x) = \Phi(x) e^{x^3-\frac 32 x^2+\frac 32 x-1}
$$

Here $\Phi(x)$ is any periodic function with period $1$